# when I choose from a select menu in mobile it doesn't do any thing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

when I choose from a select menu in mobile it doesn't do any thing (run validation or send data to server) till I choose the same option again it happen only in mobile ?

```js
 $("#major").click(function(){
 check_major();
 });
```

```html
  <select name="section[]" class="custom-select" id="major" >
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Electrical</option>
    <option value="2">Mechanical</option>
    <option value="3">Civil</option>
    <option value="4">Archticture</option>
  </select>
```

is the problem in event (click)
I tried blur - onchange - on(touch,function()

Comment: Use `.change()`, not `.click()`.

Comment: Few days ago I had a jquery code which refused to work until I wraped it around $(document).ready(function(){    }); Excuse me please if yours is already wraped

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call your script after the DOM content is loaded, by calling the script at the end of th DOM, or, wrap it in a `$(document).ready` function.

then, for catching the select change you need to use the `change` event

```js
var check_major = function( e ) {
  console.log( $(this).val() )
}

$("#major").on("change", check_major);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="section[]" class="custom-select" id="major" >
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Electrical</option>
    <option value="2">Mechanical</option>
    <option value="3">Civil</option>
    <option value="4">Archticture</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#major').on('change',function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="section[]" class="custom-select" id="major" >
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Electrical</option>
    <option value="2">Mechanical</option>
    <option value="3">Civil</option>
    <option value="4">Archticture</option>
  </select>
```